# Adding Website to App Store

Tags: android, websocket

I have a fairly complex site (titansoftime.com), which is powered by WebGL and WebSockets. Before I embark on learning how to create even simple android/apple apps, I would like to know if this is possible.

Can I add a functional "link" to the apple/android app stores?

This code is from the accepted answer from [Android app that just points to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794893/android-app-that-just-points-to-a-url).

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Is this a viable solution? All I really want is a way to list my game in the app store. I know users can "Add to Home" from within the browser, but it seems only a handful of people are aware of this.

Comment: you can load this URL into a webview in an android app. Why to have a link?

Comment: Cool, I'll have to try it both ways I guess and see which is better (Intent vs using a Webview). And yea, the main purpose for the link is for app visibility, so I can list among other games in the stores. Trying to figure out best path forward. Rewriting the game completely, is out of the question =]

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html for an explanation

Comment: Cool, I take a stab at going down the webview route. See what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments under the OP suggest, WebView is ABSOLUTELY the way to go. This worked flawlessly.

I've never created an app before and this guide got me from start to finish quite easily.

https://medium.com/@stevesohcot/andriod-studio-webview-tutorial-4651701d7d1a